# Freeze the 1st column of pageblock table in salesforce

Tags: visualforce

How to freeze the 1st column of pageblocktable using salesforce ?
I had tried using **position:absolute** property to fix the column header but it is not working instead the css is getting mis aligned as shown in the image

[image]
Regards,
Pravalika

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "freeze"

Comment: Hi Tezyn,
Acknowledging to your query , freeze is like I want only the Product name to be Fixed/Rigid and the rest of the columns can be scrolled-horizontally.I want the Product Name to be Fixed.

Comment: I don't know that I have an answer for you, but to help clarify what you are wanting, it sounds like you are looking for a way to create an excel like "freeze first column" experience similar to http://jsfiddle.net/emn13/YMvk9/ as offered up on http://stackoverflow.com/a/1312678/901729 by Eamon Nerbonne